# Does the compactness of parameter of distribution function imply the compactness of the distribution (or probability measure) in Wasserstein space?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, probability-distributions, metric-spaces, compactness

For a family of probability measures sharing the same form of distribution function $F(x; p)$ with different parameters (i.e., $p$'s), if the parameter falls in a compact subset of real line, can we say these probability measures constitute a compact subset in Wasserstein space?

For example, considering exponential distributions $\text{Exp}(\lambda)$ and $\lambda \in [a, b] \subset \mathbb{R}$, intuitively, it seems these exponential distributions should be in a compact subset in the sense of Wasserstein metric. If so, I am just wondering whether there is any rigorous proof for it.

Comment: This would be obvious if the dependence of the parameter is continuous.

Comment: Thank you, Jochen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the continuous image of a compact set is compact, it suffices to determine whether the mapping $p \to F(x,p)$ is continuous. This is the case for most natural parametrized families of distributions, but needs to be verified in each case. For instance, for the exponential family, the transformation $x \mapsto(1+\epsilon) x$ takes the Exp$(\lambda)$ distribution $\mu$ (which has mean $1/\lambda$) to the  Exp$(\frac{\lambda}{1+\epsilon})$ distribution $\nu$. The Wasserstein distance can be bounded using this coupling:
$$W_1(\mu,\nu) \le \int |\epsilon x| \, d\mu(x)=|\epsilon/\lambda| \,.$$
This suffices to establish continuity of the mapping $\lambda \mapsto$ Exp$(\lambda)$.

Comment: Thank you, Yuval! Following https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/1118101, I think we could calculate the 1-Wasserstein distance exactly (i.e., seems like we could replace the inequality into equality)
\begin{align*}
W_1(\mu, \nu) &= \int \big|F(x)-G(x)\big| dx 
\\
&= \int \big|\big(1-F(x)\big)-\big(1-G(x)\big)\big| dx 
\\
&=\int \big|\bar{F}(x)-\bar{G}(x)\big| dx
\\
&=\int \big(\bar{F}(x)-\bar{G}(x)\big) dx
\\
&=\int \bar{F}(x) dx - \int \bar{G}(x) dx =\left| \frac{\epsilon}{\lambda} \right|
\end{align*}
where $F(\cdot)$ and $G(\cdot)$ are the CDFs of $\mu$ and $\nu$, respectively.

Comment: Yes indeed.  The upper bound was the only direction needed for continuity.

Comment: I see, thank you!

Comment: I assume you know how to accept an answer :-)